# Anyone know a good web-based file upload package?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, upload

Basically, what I'm looking for is a place for either one of our end users to be able to upload a file to this package, after either receiving a code from one of our support engineers or vice-versa(our engineers upload a file and send a code/link/something to end user)

I've spent a bunch of time googling this, I found this: http://turin.nss.udel.edu/programming/dropbox2/, but the code there scares me, and it also doesn't render properly using PHP 5.3(uses short tags, who knows what else.)

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

here is one very simple solution, a single PHP file:
http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/

It has all basic things you might need and it is very easy to use :)

Comment: The demo still works today (April 2019) and continues to evolve at https://github.com/dulldusk/phpfm . That said, phpfm does much more than just web upload, and it does not appear to support upload by drag-and-drop.